# Google API giving request denied error in Android native app

Tags: android, google-maps

The url
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Pune&sensor=false/true
works fine on desktop browser but when I am calling same from android native app it's giving me Request Denied error.

Any gueses?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are trying like this :

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=pune&sensor=false/true
```

Try to this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=pune&sensor=false
```

And make sensor value `true` or `false` according to your requirement.

And result that I got is [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=pune&sensor=false).

Comment: I have tried with both the options true as well as false but still same error........